# Why total time during elasticsearch profile is not equals to time sum?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have added `profile: true` to es query and got request time `54518`:

{
    "took" : 54518,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
      "total" : 170,
      "successful" : 170,
      "failed" : 0
    }

But when I summed up all time field from `profile` section in responce I got only `864ms` e.g. this is **not even** a second!

Why? Where to see the gap between shard timing and total response time?

Comment: would be helpful if you posted the query and the breakdown

Comment: I'll try tomorrow, but responce is about 3mb :(

Answer (score 0):

It should be the reason for parallelism.

1. The profile returns the time of each fragment request, and each fragment has a unique id. For example:
   "id": "[2aE02wS1R8q_QFnYu6vDVQ][twitter][0]
2. The retrieval is performed for multiple or N fragments of one or more indexes.

Since multiple shards are operated in parallel, the sum of the individual shards is not equal to the total retrieval time.